# Es mejor una columna con delimitadores, o una tabla nueva

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos

No sabía qué título poner, mi consulta es esta, tengo tiendas registradas en una BD Mysql así:

```
Cod     Nombre    Productos
 1     Don Pepe  2_1.5_9_2022-01-31,1_1.8_2_2022-01-31
```

El formato de la columna Productos es así: `Código_PrecioUnitario_Stock_FechaVencimiento,` La '`,`' hace referencia a otro producto, para que con Explode de PHP separe primero por '`,`' y luego por '`_`' dándome un array Bidimensional de cada producto con su precio y stock, lo hice así porque cada tienda maneja su propio Stock, Fecha de Vencimiento y Precio de un mismo producto, en una tienda puede costar $1 y en otra $1.5 por eso el Stock, Precio y Fecha de Vencimiento no están en la tabla de productos (otra tabla aparte):

```
Cod     Nombre     Categoría
 1       Atún      Abarrotes
 2       Fideos    Abarrotes
```

Bueno mi consulta es que la tienda no solo tiene 2 productos, tiene más de 10000, y cuando busco un producto, tengo que leer los 10000 concatenados ya que eso me devuelve el select, separarlos por comas, luego por _ y luego buscar el producto que quiero, está bien hacer de ese modo? o mejor crear otra tabla? o de qué forma sería más efectivo manejarlo?

Comment: EN la forma como está hecha la pregunta, está buscando opiniones. Uno puede opinar que sí, que está mal normalizado el modelo de datos y por eso tienes unas cosas concatenadas en vez de tener una tabla separada con cada elemento y su código. Alguien más diría que el costo de rehacer la capa de persistencia puede ser muy alto si ya esto está en producción, etc. Lo que sí sabemos es que el mantenimiento de eso no va a ser agradable y que, si ya tienes concatenados 10000 elementos en un mismo registro, eso es ilegible al hacer debug.

Comment: O tal vez mi pregunta pueda ser: Qué tarda más? buscar una fila de entre 10 Millones de filas de una tabla en una BD, o crear un array de 100k indices a partir de un string concatenado y buscar una fila entre los 100k indices con un bucle?

Comment: Corriste alguna prueba? Viste diferencias? Buscar una fila entre 10MM puede ser muy rápido dependiendo del indexado y la selectividad de los índices; buscar entre 100k registros y manipular un string que toca explotar siempre, eso suena caro. Hacer full scan todas las veces (lo que haces con el concatenado) es irse siempre por el caso pesimista; normalizar es hacer que los árboles B+ de los índices mejoren la búsqueda _en promedio_. La única verdad son los datos, correr EXPLAIN ANALYZE sobre cada consulta con datos de prueba, suficientes veces para vercómo se comporta eso en promedio...

Comment: ¿Cuál es la ventaja de guardar datos así: `2_1.5_9_2022-01-31,1_1.8_2_2022-01-31`? Diría que **ninguna**, y diría que eso es un insulto a los SGBD. Un modelo de datos pensado así no resiste a la más mínima evolución, y hace complicado cualquier reporte simple que sea requerido. No te digo nada si te piden algo medianamente complejo como: *los reportes entre los años 2018 y 2022 que sean mayores a tal cantidad ocurridos en la ciudad tal pero cuyos vendedores empezaron a trabajar en el año tal*. En una BD debidamente normalizada esto sería simple en una sola consulta SQL, pero en tu modelo ...

Comment: ... te veo echándole el muerto a PHP, haciendo unos explode verdaderamente endiablados para sacar a duras penas un reporte, repito, medianamente complicado. Y no digamos nada de la rapidez, del aprovechamiento de los índices, o si se agrega complejijdad a las cosas, como un simple orden según determinado criterio ... no podrás usar `ORDER BY`  y volverás a echarle el muerto a PHP, para que te ordene los datos sacados después de haber escrito 1,500 líneas de código, las cuales, quizá, provoquen datos erróneos, porque además hubo fallos al guardar tu trabalengua de datos en una sola columna.